# Make an environment variable accessible from a formula

Tags: ruby, environment-variables, homebrew

I try to write a private homebrew tap for gitlab thanks to this article: https://wheniwork.engineering/creating-a-private-homebrew-tap-with-gitlab-8800c453d893

Here is my formula:

```
class Pouet < Formula
  desc "Pouet command line utility"
  homepage "https://gitlab.mycompany.com/martin/Pouet"
  url "https://gitlab.mycompany.com/api/v4/projects/0000017/repository/archive?private_token=#{ENV['HOMEBREW_GITLAB_TOKEN']}"
  version "1.0"
  sha256 "ffdb029ada6d03fe3fa323577693cc233ef3d2300784a8d79077cecf6df7a470"
def install
    system "echo", ENV["HOMEBREW_GITLAB_TOKEN"]
  end
  test do
    pouet --help
  end
end
```

I defined `HOMEBREW_GITLAB_TOKEN` in my environment so it is accessible from the shell from which I launch the `brew` command.

Unfortunately the download fails because the `HOMEBREW_GITLAB_TOKEN` variable is not known from the `brew` process.

Any idea?

Comment: how have you defined the env var? Is it exported?

Comment: yes (see my edit)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Homebrew has multiple levels of environment variable filtering.  The first that gets encountered relates to the previous version of your question where you had the variable `GITLAB_HOMEBREW_TOKEN`.  Homebrew's [initial filtering](https://brew.sh/2017/12/11/homebrew-1.4.0/) allows only [specific environment variables](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/bin/brew#L79-L83) to get passed through to `brew` commands to avoid contaminating the build environment.  So, `GITLAB_HOMEBREW_TOKEN` wouldn't get passed because it didn't start with `HOMEBREW_` (or match any other whitelisted variables).

The second level of filtering is the one you're currently hitting where "sensitive" environment variables [get filtered](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/4897ec02d0f00c37a21ddaa0bebff6b83b27d027/Library/Homebrew/extend/ENV.rb#L32) if they match the following Ruby regular expression:

```
/(cookie|key|token|password)/i
```

Because your variable has the keyword `TOKEN` in the variable name it gets filtered out before it reaches your Formula.

In short, you need to use a different environment variable name that *starts* with `HOMEBREW_`, such as:

```
HOMEBREW_GITLAB_SECRET=secretsquirrel brew install Pouet
```

and you'll have access to this in your Formula's Ruby code.

See also https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook#using-environment-variables for the background on the types of environment variable filtering that exists.

Comment: Thanks I ignored the second level of filtering!

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `$` from the env variable name

```
system "echo", ENV["GITLAB_HOMEBREW_TOKEN"]
```

See:

```
[1] pry(main)> ENV['LC_NAME']
=> "pl_PL.UTF-8"
[2] pry(main)> ENV['$LC_NAME']
=> nil
```

Comment: I removed it but it didn't work so I edited my question

Comment: Do you have it in your shell when you do `echo $GITLAB_HOMEBREW_TOKEN`?

Comment: yes of course I checked (I just edit my question to precise that)